# schedule automate shell script running not as ROOT

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, linux-kernel

I have a  shell script that I want to run automatically every day at 08 AM, and I am not authorised to use the crontab because I don't have `root` permission

My home directory is `/home/user1/`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Setup a timer function to run the script at a given time. You could use whatever language comes easy to you

Comment: You don't need to be root to use `cron`, just to be in the `cron` user group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should have your system administrator add your user account to `/etc/cron.allow` - without that you do not have permission to use the [`crontab`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) command, as you probably discovered.

If that is not possible, then you could use a wrapper shell script along these lines (note: untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

TIME="tomorrow 8am"

while :; do
    # Get the current time in seconds since the Epoch
    CURRENT=$(date +%s)
    # Get the next start time in seconds
    NEXT=$(date +%s -d "$TIME")

    # Sleep for the intervening time
    sleep $((NEXT-CURRENT))

    # Execute the command to repeat
    /home/user1/mycommand.sh
done
```

You start the wrapper script in the background, or e.g. in a `screen` session, and as long as it's active it will regularly execute your script. Keep in mind that:

- Much like `cron` there is no real accuracy w.r.t. the start time. If you care about timing to the second, then this is not the way to go.
- If the script is interrupted for whatever reason, such as a server reboot, you will have to somehow restart. Normally I'd suggest an `@reboot` entry in `crontab`, but that seems to not be an option for you.
- If there is some sort of process-cleaning mechanism that kills long-term user processed you are probably out of luck.
- Your system administrator may have simply neglected to allow users access to `cron` - or it may have been an explicit decision. In the second case they might not take too well to you leaving a couple of processes overnight in order to bypass that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you dont have root permission you can set cron job. Chcek these 2 commands as user1, if you can modify it or its throwing any error.

`crontab -l`

If you can see then try this as well:

`crontab -e`

If you can open and edit, then you can run that script with cron.

by adding this line:

`*  08  *  *  *    /path/to/your/script`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think root permission is required to create a cron job. Editing a cronjob that's not owned by you - there's where you'd need root.

Comment: Actually it depends on the flavor of the `cron` daemon in question. On my own system that uses `cronie`, a fork of `vixie-cron`, a user must exist in `/etc/cron.allow` for them to be able to edit their own crontab.

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch, you can use `at`(1). Make sure the program you run reschedules the at job.  Warning: this goes to heck if the machine is down for any length of time.